# why my first jqm program is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I am learning 'Jquery Mobile' programming.

I wrote a program, but it is not working.

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css' />


<link rel="stylesheet" href='../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../jquery.mobile-1.4.5/demos/js/jquery.min.js'></script></head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect (slides to the next page from right to left).</p>
    <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide">Slide to Page Two</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">   <h1>Footer Text</h1>    </div>
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the link to see the slide effect REVERSED (slides to the previous page from left to right).</p>
    <a href="#pageone" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Slide to Page One (reversed)</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer"> <h1>Footer Text</h1>    </div>
</div> 
</body></html>
```

The css styles and data-role attributes are not working properly.
Its just showing both pages at a time as HTML page.

The .css files and .js files are in correct path.

Comment: Load jquery before jquery-mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed three problems in your code.First you should either use the jquery- mobile css or the minified version of jquery-mobile css but not both.In your code you have used both.Another error I noticed in your code is given below.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
```

You have used two div elements with data-role="page" attribute with the same id value.Finally when you include the jquery js,always put it on top of jquery-mobile js.

Comment: jQuery **must** be loaded before jQM.

Comment: I did what you said. Now a  ..loading mask came with console error :
----
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///D:/nageswar/UI_Programs/html/jqm_hello.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///D:/nageswar/UI_Programs/html/jqm_hello.html'.

Comment: @NageswaraRao.K use localhost. Download Apache server.

Comment: hi kiran.. I found the solution.  I checked the page in other browsers. its working.....

Comment: @NageswaraRao Ok.If you found my answer useful,mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the libraries in this order:

1. jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
2. jquery.min.js
3. jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

And deleting the duplicated `pageone` `div`.

Comment: jcarrera, I did what you said. Now a  ..loading mask came with console error :
----
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///D:/nageswar/UI_Programs/html/jqm_hello.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///D:/nageswar/UI_Programs/html/jqm_hello.html'.

Comment: jcarrera.. I found the solution.  I checked the page in other browsers. its working.